# I want to give privileges to the users of my point of sale but I don't know how, any suggestions?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, get, null

I have a problem, I have a system that is a point of sale made in netBeans, 2 users can register in my system: "Administrador" and "Vendedor", there are several modules in the system, including the "Inventario" module that allows you to enter, modify, delete and search for articles in the database, the problem is that I want only the administrator to have permission to enter that module, and that the seller cannot access it.

I had an idea that it was to put a code like this in the "Inventario" button method to prohibit it from entering but it didn't work for me, the code was like this:

```
//"usu" is the object of the "Login" class, which is where I declare the sets and gets of the user information, and "admin" is the name that is assigned to someone in the "tipoUsuario" variable when you register them as admin 
    String tUsuario=usu.getTipoUsuario();

   
    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

The problem is that the code didn't work, and when printing what value the "getTipoUsuario" was taking, it told me that it was returning the value "null".
I know that the code is probably wrong and doesn't work since I'm new to programming.
Try another code that is the following, to try to take the value of the "tipoUsuario" variable through the "id_usuario" variable, the code is the following:

```
//"login" is the class where I have all the information of the users, the sets and gets, "usuarios" is the object of another class called "loginDAO" in which I have the method "ListarUsuarios()"

List<login> ListarUsuario = usuarios.ListarUsuarios();
   modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaUsuarios.getModel();
    Object [] ob = new Object[4];
    for(int i=0; i < ListarUsuario.size();i++){
        ob[0] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getId_usuario();
        ob[1] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getTipoUsuario();
        ob[2] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getNombre();
        //ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_paterno();
        //ob[4] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_materno();
        ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getContrasena();
        modelo.addRow(ob);
    }
        int tID  = usu.getId_usuario();
    String tUsuario = ListarUsuario.get(tID).getTipoUsuario();//usu.getTipoUsuario();
   
    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

The problem with the previous code is that when I gave print to the value of "tUsuario" it always gave me the typeUser of the first one in the list, not of the others.

Below I leave the code of the "ListarUsuarios" method that is in another class called "LoginDAO":

```
public List ListarUsuarios(){
    List<login> ListaUsuarios = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    try{
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            login ld = new login();
            ld.setId_usuario(rs.getInt("id_usuario"));
            ld.setTipoUsuario(rs.getString("tipoUsuario"));
            ld.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            //ld.setApellido_paterno(rs.getString("apellido_paterno"));
            //ld.setApellido_materno(rs.getString("apellido_materno"));
            ld.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
            ListaUsuarios.add(ld);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return ListaUsuarios;
}
```

And finally I leave you the code of the "login" class, which is where the sets and gets of the information of each user are located:

```
package Modelo;
//Constructor para varibles del Usario con getters y seters
public class login {
private int id_usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellido_paterno;
private String apellido_materno;
private String tipoUsuario;
private String contrasena;
private String correo;
private int id_proveedor;
private String nombre_proveedor;
private String telefono_proveedor;
private String direccion_proveedor;
private String domicilio_proveedor;
private String email_proveedor;

public login() {
}

public String getDomicilio_proveedor() {
    return domicilio_proveedor;
}

public void setDomicilio_proveedor(String domicilio_proveedor) {
    this.domicilio_proveedor = domicilio_proveedor;
}

public login(int id_usuario, String nombre, String contrasena, String tipoUsuario, int id_proveedor,String nombre_proveedor,String telefono_proveedor,String direccion_proveedor,String email_proveedor) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_proveedor() {
    return id_proveedor;
}

public void setId_proveedor(int id_proveedor) {
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
}



public String getNombre_proveedor() {
    return nombre_proveedor;
}

public void setNombre_proveedor(String nombre_proveedor) {
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
}

public String getTelefono_proveedor() {
    return telefono_proveedor;
}

public void setTelefono_proveedor(String telefono_proveedor) {
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
}

public String getDireccion_proveedor() {
    return direccion_proveedor;
}

public void setDireccion_proveedor(String direccion_proveedor) {
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
}

public String getEmail_proveedor() {
    return email_proveedor;
}

public void setEmail_proveedor(String email_proveedor) {
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_usuario() {
    return id_usuario;
}

public String getApellido_paterno() {
    return apellido_paterno;
}

public void setApellido_paterno(String apellido_paterno) {
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
}

public String getApellido_materno() {
    return apellido_materno;
}

public void setApellido_materno(String apellido_materno) {
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
}

public String getTipoUsuario() {
    return tipoUsuario;
}

public void setTipoUsuario(String tipoUsuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public void setId_usuario(int id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}

}
```

Could you tell me why my codes don't work or why the variable "tUsuario" returns "null"? Or if you see that my methods are wrong, could you leave me a method that works for that?

Thank you very much and have a nice afternoon!

Try to solve with an "if" and retrieve the value of "tipoUsuario" to compare it with the string of "admin", which is the value that takes "tipoUsuarios" when the user is administrator

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable is "private"   tipoUsuario access. "Set" it with a private method. Check for all other set methods on your globals and correct them.

```
private void setTipoUsuar(String tipousuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipousuario;
}


public void setTipoUsuario(String tipousuario) {
  setTipoUsuar(tipousuario);
}
```